# LINQ filter on array

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

```
public class Feature
{
    public string Id { get;  set; }
    public string Description { get;  set; }
    public decimal Class { get;  set; }
    public decimal Price { get;  set; }
}
```

I have a `Feature[]` array. Now, when I have a populated array list, I want to:

1. filter the arraylist by removing any item with `Price = 0`.
2. And if the `[Id]` and `[Class]` are the same I want sum up the Price for those items and display as a single item.

How to achieve this with LINQ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Feature[] features = ...
var results =
    from f in features
    where f.Price != 0
    group f by new { f.Id, f.Class } into g
    select new Feature 
    {
        Id = g.Key.Id,
        Class = g.Key.Class,
        Description = g.First().Description,
        Price = g.Sum(f => f.Price)
    };
```

Or in fluent syntax:

```
var results = features
    .Where(f => f.Price != 0)
    .GroupBy(f => new { f.Id, f.Class })
    .Select(g => new Feature 
        {
            Id = g.Key.Id,
            Class = g.Key.Class,
            Description = g.First().Description,
            Price = g.Sum(f => f.Price)
        });
```

Note that this generates an entirely new set of `Feature` objects, completely unrelated to the original. Also note that filtering `f.Price != 0` is probably unnecessary here; If the price is actually 0, it won't show up in the sum anyway. The only difference is that if you don't filter out `f.Price != 0`, groups where the prices are 0 for all `Feature` in that group will in the result set.